# How to sum value in column and average

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Please help me, following below

```
name | value |   month
A        5        mar
B        6        apr
```

i need sum column value then average
how should i do.

Comment: What should be the expected result from your example?

Answer (score 0):

First create a **calculated column** as below-

```
calculated_column  = column B + column C
```

Now create the average **Measure** as below-

```
avg = AVERAGE(calculated_column)
```

Comment: Excuse me, I have changed my problem.
Can you advise?

Comment: what is your expected output from that input data?

Comment: i want to make total row a and b then average